# Why is 14.04.1 not showing up as a release upgrade for 12.04 yet?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, lts

I realize this question is a bit of a duplicate, but stack exchange won't let me comment on other questions/answers until you have 50 reputation, which seems a bit silly because it means the only way I can ask for or add clarification to an existing question is to open a whole new one.

This post asks the same question:

[Why does do-release-upgrade on 12.04 system not find 14.04.1 upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502503/why-does-do-release-upgrade-on-12-04-system-not-find-14-04-1-upgrade)

But people keep saying "Wait for the point release."  Yet if you read the question, the user did in fact specify the fact that the point release has been released.  14.04.1 has been out for 2 weeks today, and I still get this when I try to upgrade:

```
jeremy@server:~$ date
Fri Aug  8 09:38:28 CDT 2014
jeremy@server:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

I don't want to use the -d or -p option to do-release-upgrade.  I want to upgrade in the most correct/supported way possible.  if I need to wait I'll wait.  But I'm perplexed as to why it's been 2 weeks since the first LTS point release (14.04.1) has been released and my 12.04 systems still don't see it as an available upgrade path?

If the answer is wait, do we know why we're waiting or for how long?

Comment: Using the `-d` option will still put you on 14.04 and is supported (for the purposes of getting onto 14.04.x); it won't put you on 14.10.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126833/lts-to-lts-upgrade) and maybe even more relevant [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/453828/289138)

Comment: I understand that -d will put me on 14.04, but if there's a reason why the default upgrade isn't automatically moving me, I want to understand why.  I don't want to risk production machine stability if the upgrade is deemed too risky to push out yet.  My understanding is that the .1 release is supposed to be the one that's considered stable enough to push out automatically, but Ubuntu hasn't pushed it out.  I'm assuming there's a reason why they haven't, but I can't find any communication that actually explains what's going on.

Comment: The second link ^-- has it written out.

Comment: @Hannu, both of your links basically say "Wait for the .1 release", which was released 2 weeks ago, so neither of those links answer my question.

Comment: Your second link says:

"

LTS-to-LTS upgrades are always delayed until the first dotrelease (service pack) is ready. The larger differences between the two LTS versions means they need more time to get it right.

In your case, you'll be presented with an option to upgrade when Ubuntu 14.04.1 is released, which is scheduled for July 24th 2014.
"

This was 2 weeks ago and it still isn't showing up.

Comment: Yes, ... and do you have reason for such hurry? There is an [1204_HWE_EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL), yes... but that will as far as I can see just stop **UPDATES**, not stop your hardware from **working**. Anyway I'm not aware of how many people actually work with the upgrade full time, nor what the issues might be - or if it just is a 'stability check period' of some sorts.

Comment: Because there are features in 14.04 that I'd like to have.  Why is it relevant "why I'm in a hurry?"  We were told the upgrade would push out when the .1 release was released.  It was released 2 weeks ago.  It seems like a perfectly valid question to ask then why the upgrade hasn't been pushed?  I don't understand why everyone continues to say "Wait for the point release" when the point release has been out for 2 weeks now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Update Manager is now prompting me to upgrade.  I didn't even need to go to the command line.

I'd still like to know why it took 3 weeks from the release of 14.04.1 to get pushed out, or at least how to anticipate when it was getting pushed out.

It's hard to plan upgrades when you have no idea when the upgrade is going to be available.